# Calculating average of a column using python flask from MySQL Database : NameError: name 'rate' is not defined

Tags: python, mysql, flask, mysql-python, nameerror

I am trying to calculate the average of a column named `rate` from a MySQL database table named `jacket` using python (MySQLdb) on a flask server.
I tried

```
c.execute("""SELECT AVG(%s) FROM jacket""",(rate))

avg = c.fetchone()
```

The app runs without any errors but the query does not return any results. 
Also in cmd I get the error :
`c.execute("""SELECT AVG(%s) FROM jacket""",(rate))
 NameError: name 'rate' is not defined`

What does this mean? What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Parameterization is intended for literal values not identifiers like table and column names.

Answer (score 1):

you can calculate avg for column as like below

```
c.execute("""SELECT AVG(rate) AS avg_rate FROM jacket """)

avg = c.fetchone()
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can connect to db as first line.
Then you should create a cursor for write queries.
You can create a query as a string.
If you give your query as a parameter to execute function and fetch your result you can handle it.

```
conn = mysql.connect()
cursor =conn.cursor()
query = "SELECT AVG(rate) from User"
cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchall() # or fetchone()
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.